# Why not add ‘the’ before ‘wallet’？

Tags: articles

> John had a very good day and put his wallet containing £3,000 into the microwave oven for safekeeping. Then he and Jane went horse-riding. When they got home, Jane cooked their dinner in the microwave oven and without realizing it, cooked her fiancé's wallet as well. Imagine their dismay when they found a beautifully-cooked wallet and notes turned to ash! John went to see his bank manager who sent the remains of **wallet** and the money to the special department of the Bank of England in Newcastle: the Mutilated Ladies!

I feel that before the **wallet**, **the** should be added.

Comment: Yes, it should. But that makes it difficult to write an interesting answer to your question, so I will vote to close.  (Also, microwaves don't work like that)

Comment: It should be the wallet and the money, or wallet and money. "Remains of wallet and money" is correct, but I don't know what the rule is. Because of this alternative the question should remain open.

Comment: This quote needs a source.  Where exactly did you read this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because sources need to be always cited. This was originally someone asking a community to proofread their text/story/corrections. The recording has the missing "the".

Comment: http://edu.szmdata.com/NCE/3/Lesson%2007.html It's a typo, the recording of the story (which is a far-fetched story) has the missing "the" in : who sent the remains of [the] wallet .

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not a good answer. Perhaps someone can do better?

You are correct in thinking it should say **the** wallet because **the** money is specified. Two specific objects are identified. When identifying two or subjects in a group a definitive article should proceed the first noun (subject), and each noun afterwards if desired (Too much use of *the* gets tedious. (The wallet, the money, and the whole ruined mess).

I have never seen an instance where **the** is used to identify a second subject and not the first. Peter also identified not using **the** at all, because the two items are combined into one item (wallet and money)

Comment: Going out on a limb here but I think this needs a proper answer. Sure it doesn't sound grammatical to the native speaker, but why? What's the rule I can't seem to name?

Comment: I think the key feature is that here 'wallet and money' comprise multiple things considered together (because they were cooked together, and sent together in one package to the Bank of England). Although it is correct to write (or say) 'the wallet and the money', the 'rule' (if you want to call it that) is that we can avoid repetition of articles in a list if they would be tedious for the reader or hearer, and the emphasis is on the list considered as a whole. I killed the snake, the spider, and the toad. I want a house with garden, hot tub, and pool.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But there is a **the** before **money**. If **wallet and money** are comprised together, it shouldn't be add a **the** before **money**. Am I right?

Comment: @Y.zeng - the remains of money and wallet, the remains of the money and the wallet. Both possible.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What about **the remains of the money and wallet**?

Comment: Yes, that too. You are getting the idea that English is flexible.